# Why is Paypal refusing to take description and currency value parameters?

Tags: reactjs, paypal

Language: React.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"

const PayPalButton = window.paypal.Buttons.driver("react", { React, ReactDOM });

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  createOrder(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.create({
      purchase_units: [
        {
          desciption: "Two books",
          amount: {
            value: "999",
          },
          payee: {
            email_address: 'sb-xupnm6876262@business.example.com'
          }
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  onApprove(data, actions) {
    return actions.order.capture();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <PayPalButton
        createOrder={(data, actions) => this.createOrder(data, actions)}
        onApprove={(data, actions) => this.onApprove(data, actions)}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default YourComponent;
```

The script is running perfectly however I cannot set to a different currecy. If I add "*currency_code: "AUD"*", then the button doesn't work. Also, the descriptions, are not getting recorded. Any idea why this is the case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The currency must be specified in two places, in the `src` of the script when it is loaded, and within the `amount` of the [v2 order](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders-create-request-body) when it is created. The default value is USD, and the two currencies must be the same. If they are ever not the same, the checkout will error.

Comment: Where can I find the src?

Comment: Wherever you load the PayPal JS SDK script.